# jGit possible to get all commits between a ref and head?

Tags: java, git, between, jgit

Is it possible to get all git commits between a ref and HEAD with jGit?

Like `refs/tags/rel-v1.5.0` and `HEAD`

I found a nice small piece of code that does it with two refs: https://gist.github.com/paulwellnerbou/67c1758055710a7eb88e

If I replace the second ref with HEAD I get a lot of commits, even some that are older than the refs itself. How do I get just the commits between the ref and HEAD aka. last commit?

Comment: Without the actual repository - or even better a self-contained snippet that fills a repository with commits and tags - it is difficult to say what's wrong here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just read some stuff and edit my problem/question for better understanding

Comment: The `LogCommand` as shown in the linked code snippet should work. You need to show a standalone example for others to be able to reproduce your problem.